# make bundler work for many RoR projects with different rails versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

So, seems everybody that works with bundler only have one project running at once into their machine.
I have two projects now that i'm working on, both are RoR, the former uses rails 3.0.5 and was intended to run on ruby 1.8.7, while the latter uses 3.2.9 and is intended to run on ruby 1.9.3, so I want both to work on my machine.
I'm newbie in this Ruby on Rails stuff, so as I've seen, whenever you want your enviroment to work, you must configure your Gemfile and then run:

```
bundle install
```

So, do I have to run (and by logic install and uninstall gems) for each project every time i want to run it ?

Is there another way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only need to run `bundler install` when you've either changed your `Gemfile` specification, re-installed Ruby or installed a newer release that doesn't have your gems installed, or you want to update your `Gemfile.lock`.

The reason bundler was created was to allow several projects work in parallel. At any time I have about 15-20 different apps all managed by bundler and it works well.

If you want to switch to a particular version of Ruby for each project, you can use either [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [rvm](http://rvm.io/) to manage this.

Comment: @tandman thanks for your feedback, i'm new in rails enviroment, so many info to process, will do my best, regards.

Answer (score 0):

[RVM](https://rvm.io/) was made for exactly this case.

Use it, put a `.rvmrc` file in the root of each project and it will switch ruby version for you automagically. It's pretty much the best thing ever.

Answer (score 0):

There are two answers:

- rvm (ruby version manager)
- rbenv

Both allow you to create environments with different versions of gems, ruby versions and lots more.

Both work with bundler, as long as you preface commands like "rake" and others with `bundle exec rake foo:bar`